# VS2010 Missing "Show All Settings"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Using VS2010 I wanted to turn on line numbering.

I went to:
**Tools -> Options -> Environment** with the intention of going to **"All Languages"** but the option wasn't there - neither was there an option for C# (which was the environment I specified at installation).

So I thought I just need to click **"Show All Settings"** in the bottom left corner... but it's not there.

All I really want is to turn on the line numbers but I'm kind of stumped without the right options being available.

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can turn on the Line number by going to:

Tools>Option>Text Editor>All Languages> General> mark the the Checkbox of Line numbers as Checked.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165340%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> To display line numbers in code
>   1.
>   On the menu bar, choose Tools, Options.
>   2.
>   In the categories list on the left side of the Options window, expand the Text Editor node.
>   3.
>   Perform one of the following steps:
>   ◦ To set this option globally, expand the All Languages subfolder.
>   Depending on your language or setttings, you may also need to select the Show All Settings check box in the Options window to reveal the All Languages subfolder that this procedure mentions. 
>   ◦To set this option for a specific language such as Basic, C#, F#, open the subfolder for that language.
>   4.
>   Choose the General option.
>   5.
>   In the Display section, choose Line numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I was obviously looking under the wrong node but I still don't know why "Show All Settings" doesn't show. Anyway, at least I now have my line numbers!

Comment: Unfortunately I can only accept one answer and Raj answered just before you did - but your answer is perfectly correct and I'm grateful for the rapid response.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> TextEditor -> AllLanguages

For C#
Tools -> Options -> TextEditor -> C#